# Rails "self.primary_key = 'another_key'" isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses a legacy database so most tables and ids aren't in the Rails format. The whole app uses `set_table_name` and `set_primary_key`, and as we've recently migrated to 3.2 from 3.0, we're getting a whole bunch of deprecation warning.

The suggestion is to use `self.primary_key = 'another_key'`, however for some reason this approach is not working.

I'm using FactoryGirl to build and save the models, and when it tries to save the model it gives me the following error: (on an Oracle database)

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   OCIError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (sql string)
```

Basically from what I understood, the custom primary_key is not being correctly set, and ends up as being nil, which obviously will raise this error. The SQL string has the correct custom PK, but it seems that the value being passed to it is null.

Is there any fix for that? If I keep the deprecated set_primary_key it works flawlessly, but I know it's depreceted and I don't want to keep using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Turns out that in some files I was doing

```
self.primary_key = :some_key
```

This was failing because I'm passing a symbol, and not a string. Changing `:some_key` to string everywhere solved the issue.